# Thread Inside Broadcast Receiver Android

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, looper

I am getting a DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast upon getting I am required to extract the zip file and fill the the data base I have written the code to do my work .But I have to start the Thread here to handle the file extraction and insertion to database.

I know that a thread cannot be started inside broadcast receiver . If any body has encounter the problem please suggest the solution .. as my work will take time in insertion so i dont want to wait and stick with it.

I am getting exception while running thread inside broadcast receiver and

Writing this code also not working inside broadcast receiver

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

        /*
         * check status message whether the last queue is successful and
         * completed and then stop self
         */
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(downloadmanager1.this, DBService.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(mHandler));
            mIntent.putExtra("enqueue", enqueue);
            ctxt.startService(mIntent);
          //  ctxt.startService(mIntent);
        }
    }
```

Note - no exception or error is through and neither any Intentservice is started in DDMS while debugging
    };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Write an `IntentService` that does the work to "to handle the file extraction and insertion to database".

Step #2: Call `startService()` from `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver` to pass control to the `IntentService`.

Comment: @CommonsWare why thread inside broadcast receiver does not worked? i was getting a same issue in one of my project. please explain!

Comment: @Hardik because a broadcast receiver will most likely be killed by android after the onReceive() is done.